# What is the imfilter() equivalent of a nlfilter() function?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a section of code that calculates the percent of pixels in a binary grid with value == 1 using a 50x50 sliding window:

```
f = @(x) numel(x(x==1))/numel(x);
I2 = nlfilter(buffer,[50 50],f);
```

I have heard that [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) is a more efficient way to make focal calculations and, as such, hope to do some benchmarking.  **What is the imfilter() equivalent of the above nlfilter() function?**

The complete code with sample data is attached

---

```
% Generate a grid of 0's to begin with.
m = zeros(400, 400, 'uint8');

% Generate 100 random "trees".
numRandom = 100;
linearIndices = randi(numel(m), 1, numRandom);

% Assign a radius value of 1-12 to each tree
m(linearIndices) = randi(12, [numel(linearIndices) 1]);

buffer = false(size(m));
for radius =1:12 % update to actual range
    im_r  = m==radius;
    se    = strel('disk',radius);
    im_rb = imfilter(im_r, double(se.getnhood()));

    buffer = buffer | im_rb;
end


% The imfilter approach


% The nlfilter approach
f = @(x) numel(x(x==1))/numel(x);
I2 = nlfilter(buffer,[50 50],f);
imshowpair(buffer,I2, 'montage')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binary images (only 0s and 1s), what you have done is simple summation in a sliding window. Thus, the average filter of [imfilter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) can be adopted here as:

```
h  = fspecial( 'average', 50 );
I2 = imfilter( double( buffer ), h );
```

Comment: I run the code. The problem is: you should convert buffer to double.